# Skip jbuilder files when I generate a scaffold?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scaffold, jbuilder

When I scaffold I don't want it to generate these files:

```
invoke    jbuilder
create      app/views/tests/index.json.jbuilder
create      app/views/tests/show.json.jbuilder
```

But how? in my **application.rb** I have this:

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.assets            false
  g.helper            false
  g.test_framework    nil
end
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use

`config.generators.jbuilder = false`

or

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.assets            false
  g.helper            false
  g.test_framework    nil
  g.jbuilder          false
end
```

Comment: According to this [article](http://rubyjunky.com/rails-scaffold-dangerous-defaults.html), you'll also need to change your routes to constraint the format to ony html. Otherwise, you'll get 500 error when trying to access the json route.

Comment: For Rails 5 users still not able to disable jbuilder, downgrade thor: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40986923/meaning-of-expected-string-default-value-for-on-ruby-on-rails/41035588#41035588.

Answer (score 2):

Deleting or commenting out `jbuilder` from you `Gemfile` will do the trick.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24104811/5521564

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't created the application yet, then you can do the following:

```
rails new hello_world --skip-jbuilder
```